# Problems with adding pictures to gallery page

Tags: css, shadowbox

I have a gallery page that looks pretty good, but I need to add my own pictures of myself and/or family... I've tried to do so but it isn't working the way it should.

Here a codepen of the problem: https://codepen.io/AJ2021/pen/EOWYvm`enter code here`

I need my photos to be in a shadowbox so I have a thumbnail on the page and when I click on it, it opens in a large view.

Comment: The broken image symbol next to the picture showing on the screen is the thumbnail picture, it shows on Dreamweaver but not in the codepen. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the codepen has the exact same code your dreamweaver does, I found an error in the snippet.

It originally was:

```
<a href="../Documents/SU Fall 2017/Foltz_class/img_Lawtons_Marina.jpg"></a>" alt=""/> rel="shadowbox[picture]" title="a">
    <img src="../Documents/SU Fall 2017/Foltz class/tmb_Lawtons_Marina.jpg">
  </a>
```

Now it's:

```
<a href="../Documents/SU Fall 2017/Foltz_class/img_Lawtons_Marina.jpg" alt="" rel="shadowbox[picture]" title="a">
    <img src="../Documents/SU Fall 2017/Foltz class/tmb_Lawtons_Marina.jpg">
  </a>
```

It looks like the anchor tag `<a>` had closed too early.

Comment: Thanks but now the shadowbox image is not showing but the thumbnail on the page is...Why is that?